# Che vuol dire "elementi di fatto"?

Tags: meaning

Nel racconto *Fosforo* dal libro *Il sistema periodico*, di Primo Levi, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> In Largo Cairoli sapevo già tutto: o meglio, possedevo tutti gli **elementi di fatto**, ma talmente confusi e dislocati nella loro sequenza temporale che non mi era facile cavarne un costrutto.

Ho cercato alla voce "fatto" di alcuni dizionari, inclusi il Treccani e il *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*, ma non ho trovato la locuzione "elemento di fatto". Una ricerca su Google di "elemento di fatto" o di "elementi di fatto", però, dà parecchie occorrenze. Anche con la funzione "ricerca in sequenza" del *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana* si trovano esempi di "elemento di fatto" e di "elementi di fatto". Per esempio (grasetto mio nell'espressione "elementi di fatto"):

> Se  avessi  avuto  gli  **elementi  di  fatto**,  quest’oggi  vi  avrei letta   una   relazione   sul   valore   degl’insegnamenti,   sulla frequenza de’ giovani, sul risultato degli esami ([De  Sanctis](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI06/00000357.jpg)).

> [**Riconfinazióne,**](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI16/00130.jpg)
> sf.  Precisazione  dei  confini  di
> una  proprietà  che  non  risultano  chiaramente  nei documenti  catastali;  si  fonda  su  **elementi  di  fatto** e,  una  volta  accettata  dalle  parti  interessate,  di­viene vincolante.

> [**Riesame,**](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI16/00240.jpg)
> sm.  Nuova  valutazione,  condotta  in modo  più  approfondito  e  circostanziato  alla  luce  di nuovi  elementi  di  fatto  o  sulla  base  di  metodi e criteri  diversi  da  quelli  impiegati  in  precedenza, volta  ad  accertare  precisamente  la  natura,  la  strut­tura,  le  qualità,  le  condizioni  dell’oggetto  o  della situazione  esaminati.

Potreste spiegarmi cosa significa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per **elementi di fatto** si intende elementi *relativi ai fatti* o *che costituiscono i fatti*, cioè elementi che possono essere considerati concreti, oggettivi e verificabili.

Si potrebbe utilizzare come alternativa l'aggettivo [fattuale](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fattuale/).

Answer (score 2):

Un giudice valuta gli “elementi di fatto” e gli “elementi di diritto” quando deve [formulare una sentenza](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giudizio_di_fatto_e_di_diritto). La distinzione di solito è questa, ma la locuzione può essere usata in senso ristretto, come nel caso specifico.

Answer (score 0):

La locuzione "di fatto" (dal latino *de facto*) indica qualche cosa che è chiaramente rispondente alla verità, alla realtà, ed è assodata e dimostrata proprio dai fatti; per esempio "Di fatto, il capo è Mario" significa che Mario potrebbe non essere considerato il capo ma, in sostanza e nei fatti, e a qualsiasi fine pratico lo è. Anche *difatti*, *infatti* e *nei fatti* hanno significati avvicinabili ma si usano con scopi diversi.

Una delle interpretazioni possibili di "elementi di fatto" è quella di elementi (verità) che discendono puramente dai fatti e sono perciò automaticamente dimostrati.

Comment: È vero che *di fatto* può essere una locuzione avverbiale, ma non nel caso di *elementi di fatto*, dove è specificazione.

Comment: @egreg non ho mai parlato di locuzione avverbiale o altre forme grammaticali, mi sono limitato a fornire qualche informazione in più riguardo al significato dell'oggetto della domanda.

Comment: Ho solo precisato la natura grammaticale della locuzione *di fatto*, che mi pare sia l'oggetto del primo capoverso. E ho notato che la locuzione (avverbiale, ma non importa) ha davvero poco a che fare con la costruzione oggetto della domanda (cioè *elementi di fatto*). Perché mettere all'inizio la parte meno rilevante?

Comment: @egreg perché mi pareva che le risposte già presenti non approfondissero minimamente l'argomento, mentre altri esempi avrebbero aiutato a capire e ad avere una visione più ampia (completa). Poi, personalmente, trovo che la cosa che ho specificato per prima non sia la meno rilevante, ma la madre di tutte le altre locuzioni.